# Create space between section header and cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a grouped table view with one section header. How do I create a space between the section header and the first tableview cell?

Comment: Increase the section header height and set the view in viewForHeaderInSection accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't add space between but you can make the header height bigger and make the contents of the header not go all the way to the bottom of it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: No worries, have done this myself too.  In UICollectionView they have a property for spacers between cells and rows etc... :-D

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by

> tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

and change the height

> if(section ==0)
>         return 7; // (space between header and first row);
>     else
>       return 6;

Answer (score 0):

[Looks like this.]I solved this way and this actually create a kind of space between cell and header. Hope it helps some one.

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
  if ([tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] == 0)
  {
      return nil;
  }
  else
  {
      UIView *sectionHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
                                   CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 50.0)];

  ```
  sectionHeaderView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"2292a7"];

  UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:
                          CGRectMake(0, 0, sectionHeaderView.frame.size.width, 35.0)];

  UILabel *headerLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:
                          CGRectMake(0, 35, sectionHeaderView.frame.size.width, 10.0)];

  headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  headerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
  [headerLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:16.0]];
  [headerLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
  [sectionHeaderView addSubview:headerLabel];

  headerLabel1.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
  [sectionHeaderView addSubview:headerLabel1];

  if ([self.dateArray count] > 0)
  {
      headerLabel.text = [self.feedDateArray objectAtIndex:section];
  }

  return sectionHeaderView;
  ```

  }
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
return 10.00001
```

}